# Accessing instance of one module from inside of several other modules? (verilog)

Tags: verilog

I am writing a simple system in which there is a memory module (simple reg with a read and write signals). Now this memory has to be accessed by several other modules (not simultaneously). So I create an instance of this memory and feed data to it. But I can't figure out how will my other modules access the same instance of the memory module. Any help?

**Edit**

Let me clarify a bit by some code. This is my memory module, simple signals.

```
module rom(
    input [15:0] addr,
    input [15:0] data_in,
    input rd,
    input wr,
    input cs,
    output reg [15:0] data_out
    );

    reg [15:0] mem[255:0];
    integer k;
    initial begin
        for(k = 0;k<256;k=k+2)
            mem[k] = 16'h0011;
        for(k = 1;k<256;k=k+2)
            mem[k] = 16'h0101;
    end

    always @(cs)begin
        if(wr)
            mem[addr] <= data_in;
        if(rd)
            data_out <= mem[addr];
    end

endmodule
```

This will be instantiated in my top module, something like this

```
module Top;

    // Inputs
    reg [15:0] addr;
    reg [15:0] data_in;
    reg rd;
    reg wr;
    reg cs;

    // Outputs
    wire [15:0] data_out;

    // Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
    rom uut (
        .addr(addr), 
        .data_in(data_in), 
        .rd(rd), 
        .wr(wr), 
        .cs(cs), 
        .data_out(data_out)
    );
 ....
 ....
 ....
endmodule
```

Now this top module will also contain some other modules which would want to connect to memory. I don't really understand how I would connect them. Suppose there is one module like this

```
module IF_stage(
    input clk,
    input rst,
    output reg [15:0] pc,
    output [15:0] instruction
    );

    //pc control
    always@(posedge clk or posedge rst)
    begin
        if(rst)
            pc <= 16'hFFFF;
        else
            pc <= pc+1;
    end

 ....
```

How would I access the memory module from here?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'access the module'? You just have to connect wires to it like anything else. Can you describe the hierarchy a little more, and explain why you can't just connect the modules by ports/wires?

Comment: @Tim I can't connect them through wires (as far as I can understand). The memory module is one and all the other modules want to access data from it. So if I create an instance inside any of the other modules, it would be a different instance. How do you suggest I connect them through wires?

Answer (score 2):

Answering your comment, you don't instance the memory more than once. You create one instance of the memory at some level of the hierarchy, and then connect all the consumers to it via ports/wires. So in the top level you might have 3 modules that want to access memory, and 1 memory module. The three accessors each connect to the single instance, they don't instance their own memory.

The memory should be parallel to the other modules, not inside of them, if that makes sense.

Comment: See new code added to the question, maybe that would clarify my question

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify IF_stage to add an interface that can communicate with the memory, something like this:

```
module IF_stage(
    input clk,
    input rst,
    input [15:0] read_data_from_memory,         //new
    input        read_data_from_memory_valid,   //new
    output reg [15:0] pc,
    output [15:0] instruction

    output        do_memory_write               //new
    output        do_memory_read                //new
    output [15:0] memory_write_data             //new
    output [15:0] addr                          //new

);
```

Then when an IF_stage wants to read or write memory, it puts addr/data on it's output port to issue command to the memory module, and then waits for read_data_from_memory(_valid) to be asserted on it's input port. These outputs and inputs get connected to the memory module at the top level.

You'll also have to deal with bus contention here, for instance if two instances of IF_stage try to read/write at the same time, you'll need some kind of arbiter module to acknowledge both requests, and then forward them one at a time to the memory, and return the valid data to the proper module.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the name of your memory is "rom", which is read only. I assume it is a typo, otherwise there is no need to have wr port and you can simply implement separate roms in clients and let synthesizer to optimize the design.

For your question, basically you need an arbiter to handle the contention between multiple clients. All clients can assume they occupy the memory exclusively but the memory is shared by all clients and cannot be accessed simultaneously.

Tim is right about the IF_stage. Every client must have a separate memory interface

```
output [15:0] addr;
output [15:0] data_out;
input  [15:0] data_in;
output        wr, rd, cs;
input         rdy;          // only when rdy == 1, the memory operation is finished
```

You will need a memory controller/arbiter, which behaves as a memory to all clients but actually handle the contention among clients. Assuming there are three clients and all clients access the memory less than once per three cycles, you can simply have something as follow:

```
module mem_ctl( 
                addr_c1, dw_c1, dr_c1, wr_c1, rd_c1, cs_c1,
                addr_c2, dw_c2, dr_c2, wr_c2, rd_c2, cs_c2,
                addr_c3, dw_c3, dr_c3, wr_c3, rd_c3, cs_c3,
                addr_m, dw_m, dr_m, wr_m, rd_m, cs_m, 
                rdy_c1, rdy_c2, rdy_c3,
                rst_n, clk
              );
input        clk, rst_n;
input [15:0] addr_c1, addr_c2, addr_c3, dw_c1, dw_c2, dw_c3;  // addr and data_write from clients
output [15:0] dr_c1, dr_c2, dr_c3;                         // data read from clients
input         wr_c1, wr_c2, wr_c3, rd_c1, rd_c2, rd_c3, cs_c1, cs_c2, cs_c3; // control from clients
output [15:0] addr_m, dw_m;                                // addr and data write to memory
input [15:0]  dr_m;
output        wr_m, rd_m, cs_m;                                   // control the memory
output        rdy_c1, rdy_c2, rdy_c3;

reg [15:0]    dr_c1, dr_c2, dr_c3, dw_m, addr_m;
reg           wr_m, rd_m, cs_m;

reg [1:0]     cnt;

always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n)
  if (~rst_n)
    cnt <= 0;
  else if(cnt == 2'd2)
    cnt <= 0;
  else
    cnt <= cnt + 1;

always @(*)   // Verilog 2001, if not recognizable, fill in yourself
begin
  case(cnt)
  0: begin
     dw_m = dw_c1;
     wr_m = wr_c1;
     cs_m = cs_c1;
     rd_m = rd_c1;
     dr_c1 = dr_m;
  end
  1: begin
     dw_m = dw_c2;
     wr_m = wr_c2;
     cs_m = cs_c2;
     rd_m = rd_c2;
     dr_c2 = dr_m;
  end
  default: begin
     dw_m = dw_c3;
     wr_m = wr_c3;
     cs_m = cs_c3;
     rd_m = rd_c3;
     dr_c3 = dr_m;
  end
  endcase
end

assign rdy_c1 = (cnt == 0) & cs_c1;
assign rdy_c2 = (cnt == 1) & cs_c2;
assign rdy_c3 = (cnt == 2) & cs_c3;

endmodule
```

However, this is only OK when the access rates of all clients are lower than once per three cycles. If the access rate is variant and higher than that, you will need a real arbiter in the mem_ctl module. I think a round-robin arbiter will be fine.

The final comment, if the accumulative access rates of all clients is larger than once per cycle, it is impossible to handle in hardware. In that case, you will need to do it in other ways.