# how to map memory for 16 ports in verilog

Tags: memory, mapping, verilog

```
module testing123(Clk, Rst_n);
. . .
wire [7:0] port1_data;
wire [7:0] port2_data;
wire [7:0] port3_data;
wire [7:0] port4_data;
wire [7:0] port5_data;
wire [7:0] port6_data;
wire [7:0] port7_data;
wire [7:0] port8_data;
wire [7:0] port9_data;
wire [7:0] port10_data;
wire [7:0] port11_data;
wire [7:0] port12_data;
wire [7:0] port13_data;
wire [7:0] port14_data;
wire [7:0] port15_data;

 reg [flit_port_width-1:0] flit_out1;
 reg [flit_port_width-1:0] flit_out2;
 reg [flit_port_width-1:0] flit_out3;
 reg [flit_port_width-1:0] flit_out4; 
 reg [flit_port_width-1:0] flit_out5; 
 reg [flit_port_width-1:0] flit_out6;
 reg [flit_port_width-1:0] flit_out7;
 reg [flit_port_width-1:0] flit_out8;
 reg [flit_port_width-1:0] flit_out9;
 reg [flit_port_width-1:0] flit_out10;
 reg [flit_port_width-1:0] flit_out11;
 reg [flit_port_width-1:0] flit_out12;
 reg [flit_port_width-1:0] flit_out13;
 reg [flit_port_width-1:0] flit_out14;
 reg [flit_port_width-1:0] flit_out15;  
 . . .

RAM_Memory #(/*addr_width*/ 32'd16,
        /*data_width*/ 32'd8,
        /*lo*/ 32'd0,
        /*hi*/ 32'd63) Memory1(.clk(Clk)
,.rst(Rst_n)
,.flit_out(flit_out1)
,.dataout(port1_data)
);
RAM_Memory #(/*addr_width*/ 32'd16,
        /*data_width*/ 32'd8,
        /*lo*/ 32'd0,
        /*hi*/ 32'd63) Memory2(.clk(Clk)
,.rst(Rst_n)
,.flit_out(flit_out2)
,.dataout(port2_data)
);
RAM_Memory #(/*addr_width*/ 32'd16,
        /*data_width*/ 32'd8,
        /*lo*/ 32'd0,
        /*hi*/ 32'd63)  Memory3(.clk(Clk) ...
);
. . . 
endmodule

module RAM_Memory(
  flit_out,
 rst,
 clk,    
  dataout
);

  parameter                   addr_width = 1;
  parameter                   data_width = 1;
  parameter                   lo = 0;
  parameter                   hi = 1;

integer count, i;

input [34:0] flit_out;
input rst,clk;
output [data_width - 1 : 0] dataout;

reg we;
 reg [data_width - 1 : 0] dataout;
 reg [addr_width - 1 : 0] addr;
 reg [data_width - 1 : 0] data_in;
 reg [data_width - 1 : 0] mem [lo:hi];

 initial begin 
    count =0; i=0;
 end

 always @(posedge clk)begin
        count<=count+1;
        we<=0;
  if(count>=1) begin
         we<=1;
end 
end 

always @(we)begin 
            assign data_in = flit_out[7:0];
            assign addr = flit_out[23:8];
            mem[addr]<= data_in;
        assign dataout = mem[addr];         
    end

always @(count)begin
        if(count>=68)begin
            count<=0;
        end
    end
  endmodule
```

Here, one RAM_Memory module is given which is use in to other module testing123 by port mapping for storing data to 64 wide memory from 15 ports. But only one port memory module store 64 datas, "mem" register is not refreshing for others mapping module. Data will be loss. How to refresh the "mem" register or start from 0 value for all mapping port?

Comment: I can see your trying to store a 64 bit value bit value in 4, 16 bit wide registers (RAW_Memory). I do not see what 15 or 16 ports has to do with anything though. could you please clarify this, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Accessing instance of one module from inside of several other modules? (verilog)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10112210/4417286)

Comment: If the answer is just a link to a previous answer, it probably should have been a close vote as it is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand the question but have spotted some errors. Your code contains :

```
always @(we)begin 
        assign data_in = flit_out[7:0];
        assign addr = flit_out[23:8];
        mem[addr]<= data_in;
    assign dataout = mem[addr];         
end
```

Which contains a few issues.

1. Your triggering the always on `we` but not using `we` inside the block. This does not represent anything in hardware. It is more likely that you want a flipflop to update when enable is high.

code example

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  if (en) begin
    //..
  end
 end
```

2. Using assign inside always probably does not do what you expect.

You most likely just want :

```
always @* begin 
  data_in = filt_out[7:0]
  addr    = flit_out[23:8];
  dataout = mem[addr];
```

3. It is best practice not to mix non-blocking (`<=`) and blocking (`=`) assignments. If they are all meant to be flipflops (`@(posedge clk)`) then use non-blocking (`<=`) if it is combinatorial (`always @*`) then use blocking (`=`).

The block of code in question would become

```
always @(posedge clk)begin 
  if (we) begin
    data_in   <= flit_out[7:0];
    addr      <= flit_out[23:8];
    mem[addr] <= data_in;
    dataout   <= mem[addr];         
  end
end
```

Looking at the code I expect that is not what you want data_in and addr decoding should be done outside of this block.

```
//Semantically split the bus
assign  data_in   = flit_out[7:0];
assign  addr      = flit_out[23:8];

always @(posedge clk)begin 
  if (we) begin
    mem[addr] <= data_in;
    dataout   <= mem[addr];         
  end
end
```

Some recommendations to make reading your code easier.

Using modern port declarations makes a big difference to readability.

```
module RAM_Memory(
  flit_out,
 rst,
 clk,    
  dataout
);

  parameter                   addr_width = 1;
  parameter                   data_width = 1;
  parameter                   lo = 0;
  parameter                   hi = 1;

input [34:0] flit_out;
input rst,clk;
output [data_width - 1 : 0] dataout;
reg [data_width - 1 : 0] dataout;
```

becomes

```
module RAM_Memory#(
  parameter ADDR_WIDTH = 1, //They don not have to be upper case 
  parameter DATA_WIDTH= 1, // But most languages semantically define upper case as constants
  parameter LO = 0;
  parameter HI = 1;
)(
  input            [34:0] flit_out,
  input                   rst,
  input                   clk,    
  output [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] dataout
);
```

Your instance can move from :

```
RAM_Memory #(/*addr_width*/ 32'd16,
        /*data_width*/ 32'd8,
        /*lo*/ 32'd0,
        /*hi*/ 32'd63) Memory2(.clk(Clk)
,.rst(Rst_n)
,.flit_out(flit_out2)
,.dataout(port2_data)
);
```

to

```
RAM_Memory #(
 .ADDR_WIDTH(  6 ), //No need to specify the width of parameter
 .DATA_WIDTH(  8 ), 
 .LO        (  0 ),
 .HI        ( 63 ) 
) Memory2 (
  .clk      ( Clk       )
 ,.rst      ( Rst_n     )
 ,.flit_out ( flit_out2 )
 ,.dataout  ( port2_data)
);
```